# Django deleting where SET_NULL

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an issue with a ForeignKey and `on_delete=SET_NULL`.

When deleting the `last_data` referenced in my `Stuff` model, it also deletes the stuff object just as if this was a cascade, which is obviously not what I expected, rather setting the `last_data` field null.

Here is how my models are defined in two different django apps.

```
# App 1

class Device(models.Model):
    last_data = models.ForeignKey('Data', null=True, blank=True, related_name="last_data_device", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Latest data")

class Data(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=False, db_index=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name="data", db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


# App 2

class Stuff(models.Model):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, null=True, blank=True, related_name="stuff", db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_data = models.ForeignKey(Data, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Latest data", db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I must have misunderstood how this is linked, what I want is that a stuff object is never deleted when data is removed, but that the `last_data` reference it has may be nulled when this happens.

How should I write this or what did I do wrong here?
Thanks

PS: Migrations are up to date and db is synced.

---

Well, seing the answers given, already, it seems I should clarify.

When I do :

```
>>> stuff = Stuff.objects.get(...)
>>> stuff.last_data.delete()
```

Is that this is the **stuff** object that gets removed as "dependancy" and I cannot understand why.
What I'd expect is that the `last_data` field gets nulled and the stuff object is left alone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is due to communication OneToOneField. If you delete your last_data referenced in your Stuff model, where device connet OneToOne with Device. You can set on_delete=models.SET_NULL on your OneToOne field

Comment: When deleting either of Data or Stuff, the Device never gets deleted so this is not an issue yet

Answer (score 0):

Change to `models.DO_NOTHING`. That would avoid the delete.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your problem is that when you do:

```
>>> stuff = Stuff.objects.get(...)
>>> stuff.last_data.delete()
```

then the corresponding Data record gets removed from the database as well.

This is expected, and it's how it supposed to work. If all you want to do is to set `last_data` to `NULL`, while keeping the Data table intact, then:

```
>>> stuff.last_data = None
>>> stuff.save()
```

The purpose of `on_delete=SET_NULL` is to support the opposite use case: when you *delete a Data record*, then all Stuff records that were pointing to that Data will get their `last_data` set to `NULL`:

```
>>> stuff = Stuff.objects.get(...)
>>> stuff.last_data
<Data: ...>
>>> Data.objects.all().delete()
>>> stuff.last_data
None
```

Comment: Hi, see my edit, this is what I expect but `last_data` does not get NULL, but stuff is removed.

Comment: @d6bels: thanks for clarifying. I cannot reproduce that behavior when copying and pasting your code. Can you provide more details/relevant code?